# Converting windows date logic into Unix

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I had coded the below logic in Windows batch scripting and I need to replicate the same in Unix.

```
# Calculating  Yesterday's Date

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/- " %%a in ('date/T') do set  DY=%%c
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/- " %%a in ('date/T') do set  MON=%%b
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/- " %%a in ('date/T') do set /a YEAR=%%d


if [ $DY=="08"  ]; then DAY=8 fi
if [  $DY=="09" ]; then  DAY=9 fi
if [ $MON=="08" ]; then  MONTH=8 fi
if [ $MON=="09" ]; then  MONTH=9 fi
if [ $DY -ne "08" ]; then  if [ $DY -ne "09" ]; then DAY=%DY% fi fi
if [ $MON -ne "08" ]; then  if [ $MON -ne "09" ]; then MONTH=%MON% fi fi



PREVDAY=%DAY%-1
PREVMONTH=%MONTH%-1
PREVYEAR=%YEAR%-1
ds=%YEAR%_%MONTH%_%PREVDAY%-  


if [ %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==1 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_31- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==2 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_28- fi fi
if [ %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==3 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_31- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==4 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_30- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==5 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_31- fi fi
if [ %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==6 ] then  ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_30- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==7 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_31- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==8 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_31- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==9 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_30- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==10 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_31- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==11 ] then ds=%YEAR%_%PREVMONTH%_30- fi fi
if [  %DAY%==1 ]; then if [ %PREVMONTH%==0 ] then  ds=%PREVYEAR%_12_31- fi fi
```

Comment: Can you expand your Q showing what the various `for` commands do, for starters, expanding everything else would be helpful too. I actually know what they do but can you please expand your Q so that others who might not have access to a Windows system or are not familiar w/ these commands can have their output so they can show you how to make similar commands for them on Unix.

Comment: Please explain exactly what your script is doing and how. Most of us have absolutely no knowledge of Windows scripting and can't understand this (uncommented) code you have dumped here.  Also, we will not simply do your work for you. Read up on shell scripting, get some basic knowledge and _try something_. You can then post back here if you have specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
date -d "yesterday" "+%y_%m_%d-"
14_07_08
```

Or for 4 digit year:

```
date -d "yesterday" "+%Y_%m_%d-"
2014_07_08
```

To assign it to a variable, use:

```
d=$(date -d "yesterday" "+%y_%m_%d-")
```

Then:

```
echo "$d"
14_07_08
```

Or:

```
echo "Yesterday was $d"
Yesterday was 14_07_08
```